# How to import and export the same thing

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to achieve something like this:

```
import {colors} from '../../basestyle'
export const colours = colors
```

but with the same name for imported and exported constants.

Comment: export { colors } ... There are multiple ways to do this-just look at the MDN export page.

Answer (score 2):

To export only colors, you can do the following,

```
export { colors } from '../../basestyle';
```

To export all the exported content from '../../basestyle'; you can,

```
export * from '../../basestyle';
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't believe it. Its a one liner:

```
export * from '../../basestyle';
```

or you will be able to do this:

```
export {colors} from '../../basestyle';
```

**Update to OP's comment:**

To use it in same file and also export after importing it you can do it like this:

```
export { colors } from '../../basestyle';

const MyComponent = props => {
    console.log(colors);
    return <div>;
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: But that won't import them, right? So I guess I need 2 lines, one for import and another one for export?

Comment: @TpoM6oH For that please take a look at my updated answer.